# My paragraph font size changes as soon as i add some other paragraph or headings

Tags: html, css

I have a paragraph on my page, it looks good before I add some other paragraph or header to the page.

**HTML:**

```
<div id='info-content'>
    <p class='info-text'>Registrer bruker for å kunne enklere sette opp bestillinger, ønskelister og få tilgang til spesielle tilbud!</p>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#info-content {
width: 100%;
height: fit-content;
background-color: #ff8080;
padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
text-align: center;
color: white;
font-size: 28px;}
```

But when I add a heading under this the font size of **info-content** changes to a much bigger size.

I use chrome on my mobile because I'm making a **mDot** page for mobile devices. Does anyone know why this happens? I cant understand this.

I only get this problem when I show the page in mobile view. If I open the page on my computer in normal view in chrome the font size stays the same with and without any other heading or paragraphs. But when I press inspect and change to mobile view the problem shows up again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think  fit-content is a function and should be used with an argument. [See documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/fit-content).

Don’t you see an error in your web inspector ?

Comment: I changed **fit-content** to **130px** now and it helped! Thank you.